# Pyinstaller creates x-sharedlib file in pop os

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I use Pyinstaller in pop os for a python script but it creates a x-sharedlib file that I can only open through terminal. I tried to rename it to exe and run it but nothing happens. How I can make it open by double click? Thank you!

Comment: If you fixed the problem yourself, consider posting an answer to your own question explaining how you fixed it.

Comment: @ForceBru Thank you I will add it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I renamed it to .sh changed nautilus preferences to run executable text files and runs normally now.